# How to write a function mersenne_prime that takes the argument n_max and returns a list of all Mersenne primes q for p less than n_max?

Tags: python, function, primes

> The Mersenne primes are those numbers q = 2^p - 1 where both p and q are prime.
>   Write a function mersenne_prime that takes the argument n_max and returns a list of all Mersenne primes q for p less than n_max.
>   Hint: there should be 8 Mersenne primes with p less than 40.

I have written the following code but the only output it is producing is 3 for any value I input into mersenne_prime(x)

```
def isprime(n):
  if n < 2:
    return False
  elif n == 2:
    return True
  else:
    if n % 2 == 0:
      return False
    for i in range(3,n,2):
      if n % i == 0:
        return False
    return True


def mersenne_prime(n_max):
  for i in range(1,n_max,1):
    q = 2**i-1
    if isprime(i) and isprime(q):
     print(q)
```

Is anyone able to offer assistance in producing a working code to generate the mersenne primes?

Edit:
Changing the the return function to print works for different input value however testing the code in a different system produces an error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/unit_tests.py", line 134, in test_mersenne_prime
    assert(len(mersenne_prime(4)) ==  len(correct_list)), \
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem? Running the code provided (Python 3.8.1) I have no issues

Comment: `return` will terminate the loop. try create an empty `list` and `append(new_item)` to it. Then, return the `list` after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to compute Mersenne primes uses the Lucas-Lehmer test:

```
def primes(n): # sieve of eratosthenes
    i, p, ps, m = 0, 3, [2], n // 2
    sieve = [True] * m
    while p <= n:
        if sieve[i]:
            ps.append(p)
            for j in range((p*p-3)/2, m, p):
                sieve[j] = False
        i, p = i+1, p+2
    return ps

def lucas_lehmer(p):
    if p == 2: return True
    m, i, s = pow(2,p) - 1, 3, 4
    while i <= p:
        i, s = i+1, (pow(s,2) - 2) % m
    return s == 0

print [p for p in primes(256) if lucas_lehmer(p)]
```

That prints [2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127], which are the indices of the Mersenne primes less than 2**256.

Comment: Using this code gives an error message about invalid syntax on the final line

Comment: It works fine in Python 2. In Python 3, change the division operator in the `for j` loop of `primes` from `/` to `//` and wrap the argument of the `print` function on the last line in parentheses. You can run the program in Python 3 at [https://ideone.com/8KWCCz](https://ideone.com/8KWCCz).